# Adding a line in XML document with Square brackets

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to create an XML file for our MIS system to read and process order data.  The MIS company have provided me with a template of the XML but it contains an element (i think) within square brackets "[]".

I am struggling to find how i write the elements in as they tend to "<>" brackets.

Below is a sample of the XML i require,  im struggling to write the first and last line!

```
  [itemLoop] <!--Repeats for multiple items per order if necessary -->
<OrderLine>
   <OptionValue>
      <Name>printFileName</Name>
      <ActualValue>[printFileName]</ActualValue>
   </OptionValue>
   <OptionValue>
      <Name>printFileFtp</Name>
      <ActualValue>[printFileFtp]</ActualValue>
   </OptionValue>
   <OptionValue>
      <Name>listingDelivery</Name>
      <ActualValue>[listingDelivery]</ActualValue>
   </OptionValue>
</OrderLine>
[/itemLoop]
```

I am using "Imports system.xml" to create all of the other XML bits i need.

Comment: XML usually has an associated schema file that defines the format of the XML. Did they provide that also?

Comment: Unfortunately not, just the sample file.

Comment: I've worked with quite a few XML files and have never seen a simple XML use square brackets for delimiters or elements. Everything I'm finding says that is XSLT or XPATH notation. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#stylesheets-and-schemas Might be best to update the post with a sample from the XML you were provided.

Comment: Looks like some sort of template language and you would just repeat the `<OrderLine>` element for each order line, substituting in the values for `[printFileName]`, `[printFileFtp]` and `[listingDelivery]` for each item.  i.e. the parts in square brackets are just processing instructions, not part of the output XML.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use a `StreamWriter` to write your custom text, and then let  your `XMLWriter` write to that `StreamWriter`. Below you can find an example code for this:

```vb
    ' Initialize a basic StreamWriter to the disk
    Dim textWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\path\to\your\file.xml")

    ' Write your custom text
    textWriter.WriteLine("[itemLoop]")

    ' Do the XML Stuff
    Dim writer = New XmlTextWriter(textWriter)
    writer.Formatting  = Formatting.Indented
    writer.WriteStartElement("OrderLine")
    writer.WriteStartElement("OptionValue")
    writer.WriteElementString("Name", "printFileName")
    writer.WriteElementString("ActualValue", "[printFileName]")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndElement()

    ' Write a newline so that your text is in it's own line
    textWriter.WriteLine()

    ' Write your custom text again
    textWriter.WriteLine("[/itemLoop]")

    ' And close & dispose the TextWriter
    textWriter.Close()
    textWriter.Dispose()
```

I've added comments to the code so that it's easy for you to see how I've solved the problem.

EDIT: It prints exactly the output you wanted in the resulting XML file:

```xml
[itemLoop]
<OrderLine>
  <OptionValue>
    <Name>printFileName</Name>
    <ActualValue>[printFileName]</ActualValue>
  </OptionValue>
</OrderLine>
[/itemLoop]
```

Comment: Just for completeness, I'd like to add that you should call `StreamWriter.Dispose()` when you are done with it, or put it inside a `using` block to make sure everything gets cleaned up properly. `Close` *does* dispose the stream, but `Dispose` or `using` is more explicit.

Comment: Yep thanks, you're right I forgot about that since it was just a little demonstration. I've added that now.

Comment: Thank you I will try that and see how it work.   I’ll let you know how it goes.